# Replacing substrings in a list of strings or decoding

Tags: python, sql, string, special-characters

I have a list of strings that I will be working in PYTHON happens that some strings contain special characters: üäö and so on.

I have 2 solutions:

1. Treating the acquired data after by replacing the substring in the list of strings.
2. Decoding what is acquired in the list in python.

   lista_names_d = [ 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 2', 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 1', 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 3','L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 5' ]

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136689/find-and-replace-string-values-in-python-list)

```
lista_names_d = [name.replace('\xc3\xbc', 'ü') for name in lista_names_d]
```

This does nothing

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973815/python-to-show-special-characters)

```
your_unicode_string = "L\xc3\xbcneburg Kaltenmoor BHKW 1"
correct_unicode_string = your_unicode_string.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

**error:**
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

**Any help is highly appreciate**

Comment: are you sure with `latin1`? try `sys.stdin.encoding`

Comment: what is you db ?

Comment: python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: @StevenBENET I collect the data from sql but process on python and I use zeppelin so I guess python 3

Answer (score 0):

What about using the function `unicode`? This code prints the proper accents:

```
lista_names_d = [ 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 2', 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 1', 'L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 3','L\xc3\xbcneburg Bockelsberg 5' ]

for item in lista_names_d:
    print(unicode(item, 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Gives me the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You migth try to add this line as the first line of your code :  
In source header you can declare:`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: I added it. Still errors, unfortunately! UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Have you tried the example above as standalone? I'm asking, because there is no \xfc char in that code explicitly. (however \xc3\xbc in utf-8 is \xfc in latin-1)

Comment: yes, I did still get the error containing 'u\xfc'. I also added the header utf-8 -*- reading the documentation to get some clarity of the issue

Comment: What is your python version exactly?

Comment: I use 2.7 exactly  @Klaymen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161642/discussion-between-klaymen-and-mayra).

Answer (score 0):

Check [encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) documentation:

```
for city in lista_names_d:
    print city.decode('utf8')
# Lüneburg Bockelsberg 2
# Lüneburg Bockelsberg 1
# Lüneburg Bockelsberg 3
# Lüneburg Bockelsberg 5
```

from official documentation:

```
>>> u = unichr(40960) + u'abcd' + unichr(1972)   # Assemble a string
>>> utf8_version = u.encode('utf-8')             # Encode as UTF-8
>>> type(utf8_version), utf8_version
(<type 'str'>, '\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4')
>>> u2 = utf8_version.decode('utf-8')            # Decode using UTF-8
>>> u == u2                                      # The two strings match
True
```

Comment: does this works for you? I get an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)